# Edit specific Element in XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I recently started learning C# and I ran into a problem using `XML.Linq` to store data. I hope the question is understandable as I am not familiar with all the correct terms yet and as English isn't my first language.

I read a lot of Questions/googled but I can not figure it out myself.

I want to update an existing XDocument File that looks like this:

```
<Data>
  <IDCounter>2</IDCounter>
  <Highscores>
     .......
  </Highscores>
  <savegames>
    <savegame>
       <IdNumber>1</IdNumber>
       <salutation>Mr</salutation>
       <prename>Prename1</prename>
       <surname>Surname1</surname>
       <maximumbalance>100</maximumbalance>
       <balance>100</balance>
    </savegame>
    <savegame>
       <IdNumber>2</IdNumber>
       <salutation>Mr</salutation>
       <prename>Prename2</prename>
       <surname>Surname2</surname>
       <maximumbalance>100</maximumbalance>
       <balance>100</balance>
     </savegame>
   </savegames>
</Data>
```

What is the easiest way to change a value in a specific Element?

Let's say I want to change the **balance** of a specific **savegame**.

I want to access the savegame by **IdNumber** (these numbers are unique)

Then I want to change the value of **balance** (for example to 50) and then save these changes to my document.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

With `using System.Xml.Linq;` it becomes

```
 var doc = XElement.Load(fileName);
 var saveGame = doc
      .Element("savegames")
      .Elements("savegame")
      .Where(e => e.Element("IdNumber").Value == "2")
      .Single();

 saveGame.Element("balance").Value = "50";

 doc.Save(fileName);
```

Comment: for some reason, i have an error "Object reference not set to an instance..." then i fixed it with `XDocument.Load(fileName);`

Comment: I got "Object reference not set to an instance" as well. I found adding the XNamespace fixed this issue for me:  doc.Element(Ns + "Foo")...

Comment: An XElement can play the role of Document in almost all cases. A namespace may or may not be required by the Xml.

Answer (score 25):

I think that the most compact way of doing it is using XDocument (`System.Xml.Linq`) and XPath  extensions (`System.Xml.XPath`):

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(file);
xdoc.XPathSelectElement("//savegame/IdNumber[text()='2']/../balance").Value = "50";
xdoc.Save(file);
```

Once you learn XPath you never really want to go back to enumerating nodes manually.

EDIT: what does the query mean:

```
//savegame/IdNumber[text()='2']/../balance"
  |        |                    |  ^ balance element ...
  |        |                    ^ ... of parent ...
  |        ^ ... of IdNumber element with inner value '2' ...
  ^ ... of any savegame element in the doc
```

You can find XPath help [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp), and [the updated link here](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp).

Comment: here is the updated [link](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp) to XPath help.

Comment: here is the updated updated [link](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp) to XPath help.

Comment: To edit one value is ok, but what If I want to edit 100? it will "loop" 100 times to update the values.

Answer (score 4):

```
   UpdateGameAttr(id ,  bal);

   private void UpdateGameAttr(int id, int bal)
   {
       XDocument gmaes = XDocument.Load(@"D:\xxx\xxx\Game.xml");            

       XElement upd = (from games in games.Descendants("savegame")
                      where games.Element("IdNumber").Value == id.ToString()
                      select games).Single();
       upd.Element("balance").Value = bal.ToString();
       gmaes.Save(@"D:\xxxx\xxx\Game.xml");

   }
```

Answer (score 3):

here's a simple way to do this:

```
     XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
     doc.Load(@"d:\tmp.xml");
     XmlNode node = doc["Data"]["savegames"];

     foreach (XmlNode childNode in node.ChildNodes)
     {
        if (childNode["IdNumber"].InnerText.Equals("1"))
        {
           childNode["balance"].InnerText = "88";
        }

     }
     doc.Save(@"d:\tmp.xml");
```

this code only change the balance of id "1"

it does it by going through the children of "savegames" and checking for each item the "IdNumber"

Comment: XmlDocument is not the 'simple' way. It's the old way.

Comment: @HenkHolterman (and upvoter) you're being extremely pedantic. It was not said "*THE* simple way", merely **A** simple way. It still was simple.