# Edit existing element in XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8

I found this topic and adapted it to my XML File https://stackoverflow.com/a/18509248

My XML Code looks like this

```
<body>


    <id>1</id>
      <disc>B</disc>
      <type>Mark</type>
      <value>5</value>


    <id>2</id>
      <disc>A</disc>
      <type>Mark</type>
      <value>10</value>
    </body>
```

And C# Code to select and edit certain record looks like

```
try
            {
                var target = doc
              .DescendantsAndSelf("body")
              .Where(e => e.Element("disc").Value == Disc
                  && e.Element("type").Value.ToString().Equals(Type.ToString())
                  && e.Element("value").Value.ToString().Equals(OldMark.ToString()))
              .Single();



                Debug.WriteLine(target.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
```

The problem is that it returns the entire document and i can't figure it out why.

I use XDocument and the app is designed for WP8.1

Can you help me with this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method `DescendantsAndSelf(XName name)` returns every element that has matching name and all descendant elements of this element ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/bb300437%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). In your case that's `body` element with its children.

You probably want to form your XML like the following one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
   <someElement>
      <id>1</id>
      <disc>B</disc>
      <type>Mark</type>
      <value>5</value>
   </someElement>
   <someElement>
      <id>2</id>
      <disc>A</disc>
      <type>Mark</type>
      <value>10</value>
   </someElement>
</body>
```

so you can get single `someElement` XML node like this:

```
var target = doc.DescendantsAndSelf("someElement")
              .Where(e => e.Element("disc").Value == Disc
                  && e.Element("type").Value.ToString().Equals(Type.ToString())
                  && e.Element("value").Value.ToString().Equals(OldMark.ToString()))
              .Single();

Debug.WriteLine(target.ToString());
```