# Overwrite Select Lines in .txt File

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I have an test application that takes information from a user and saves it onto a text file. The problem arises to where certain information needs to be inserted within the structure of the list even though the user will encounter the appropriate fields much later on in the document.

[image]

I have decided to go the lazy route and put placeholders for the information I need added in the text file later on, but I have no idea how to selectively overwrite lines.

Here is the example:

Form 1:

[image]

```
using System.IO;

namespace Debug.NewFolder1
{  
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnNextInfo_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.IO.StreamWriter objwriter;
        objwriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter("Info.txt", true);
        objwriter.Write("nameL=" + tbxLast.Text);
        objwriter.WriteLine();
        objwriter.Write("nameF=" + tbxFirst.Text);
        objwriter.WriteLine();
        objwriter.Write("nameM=" + tbxMiddle.Text);
        objwriter.WriteLine();
        objwriter.Write("numberAge=" + tbxAge.Text);
        objwriter.WriteLine();

        //Occupation
        objwriter.Write("Occupation=");
        objwriter.WriteLine();
        //Certification
        objwriter.Write("Certification=");
        objwriter.WriteLine();

        objwriter.Write("Residence=" + tbxRes.Text);
        objwriter.WriteLine();
        objwriter.Close();

        NewFolder1.Form2 settingsForm = new NewFolder1.Form2();
        settingsForm.Show();
        this.Hide();
        }}}
```

Form 2:

[image]

```
using System.IO;

namespace Debug.NewFolder1
{
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnNextInfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.IO.StreamWriter objwriter;
        objwriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter("Info.txt", true);
        //skip 4 lines            
        objwriter.Write("Occupation=" + tbxOcc.Text);
        objwriter.WriteLine();
        objwriter.Write("Certification=" + tbxCert.Text);
        objwriter.WriteLine();
        //skip 1 line
        objwriter.Close();

        Application.Exit();
    }}}
```

Comment: Don't underestimate the power of [File.ReadAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx) and [File.WriteAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealllines(v=vs.110).aspx)  Maybe it will make more sense to you.

Comment: Are you dealing with small files, or really large files (where memory might be an issue)?

Comment: Does it need to be raw text?  Or could you use XML?  If you do XML you can serialize/deserialize it to an object that is easy to manipulate and then call your deserialize/write only once when you're done.  This question and answer shows how to manipulate only 1 object from xml document using the xDocument library:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18508765/edit-specific-element-in-xdocument  You can do the same thing with regular XML, in both cases I recommend you check performance if you have a large file, because I believe they will both rewrite the whole file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to look up a specific line and re-write just that line you can do something like this:

```
        string filePath = ""; //Your file path goes here
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
        string newLastName = "Smith";
        string newFirstName = "John";

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (lines[i].Contains("nameL="))
                lines[i] = "nameL=" + newLastName;

            if (lines[i].Contains("nameF="))
                lines[i] = "nameF=" + newFirstName;
        }

        File.WriteAllLines(filePath, lines);
```

Comment: sorry for the long wait, I'll test it out when I have time, but if it does not work I'll rework the OP and add pictures