# Load 2 XML's, replace matched Value with 3rd Value

Tags: c#

I'll try my best to verbalizing what it is I'm trying to do here...
I have 2 XML documents with different structures but share a common element/attribute Value.  I want to go through both documents, find the matching Value and change that in the 2nd document to a different one from the 1st document.

doc1 (truncated from 1538 *records(?)*)

```
<softwarelist name="a2600" description="Atari 2600 cartridges">
  <software name="adventp">
    <description>Adventure +</description>
    <year>2003</year>
    <publisher>Homebrew</publisher>
    <info name="programmer" value="Steve Engelhardt" />
    <sharedfeat name="compatibility" value="NTSC" />
    <part name="cart" interface="a2600_cart">
      <dataarea name="rom" size="4096">
        <rom name="Adventure Plus.a26"/>    
      </dataarea>
    </part>
  </software>
</softwarelist>
```

doc2

```
<LaunchBox>
   <Game>
      <ApplicationPath>D:\LaunchBox\Games\Atari 2600\adventp.zip</ApplicationPath>
      <CommandLine />
      <Completed>false</Completed>
      <ConfigurationCommandLine />
      <ConfigurationPath />
      <DateAdded>2019-07-22T18:00:33.7429286-07:00</DateAdded>
      <DateModified>2019-07-22T18:00:33.7429286-07:00</DateModified>
      <Developer />
      <Title>adventp</Title>
      <Genre />
   </Game>
</LaunchBox>
```

What I have to obtain the Values I need to use/reference:

```
XDocument doc1 = XDocument.Load(@"D:\temp\LB\a2600.xml");
XDocument doc2 = XDocument.Load(@"D:\temp\LB\Atari 2600.xml");

var game1 = from r in doc1.Descendants("software")
    select new
    {
        Game = r.Attribute("name").Value,
        TitleNew = r.Element("description").Value,
    };

var game2 = from r in doc2.Descendants("Game")
    select new
    {
        TitleOld = r.Element("Title").Value,
    };
```

What I want to do (in layman's terms):

```
if (TitleOld == Game)
{
    TitleOld = TitleNew;
}
```

After quite a bit of looking around (and trying to find the right search terms), interpolating between examples I found and what I'm working with is just out of reach for me.  What I think I need is something along these lines:

```
bool match = false;
int j = 0;
try
{
    // this particular list has 1538 name/Title
    // though should be a better [open ended?] way to loop
    for (int i = 0; i < 1538; i++)
    {
        while (j < 1538 && match == false)
        {
            if (Game == TitleOld)
            {
                 match = true;
                 TitleOld = TitleNew;
                 j = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                 j++;
            }
        }
   match = false;
   }
}
finally
{ 
    doc2.Save(@"D:\temp\LB\Atari 2600_new.xml");
}
```

What modifications/additions to the code I have are needed to make this work?  (Assuming what I do have is on the right track).

Edit: The Possible Duplicate points me to how to change a known (defined) single element in a single file.  I'm needing to loop through both files, and for all `doc2.Game.Title.Value` that equals `doc1.software[name].Value`, change `doc2.Game.Title.Value` to `doc1.software.description`.  I know I was having a hard time describing myself and I didn't want to "Sesame Street' it up too much so that I sound as ignorant-in-the-ways as I am. [blush] And maybe the answer is there and I just need to digest it more.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Edit specific Element in XDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18508765/edit-specific-element-in-xdocument)

Comment: @EugenePodskal That shows me how to linearly go through a single file and update a Value based on a search criteria.  Awesome examples/explanations!! and is saved in my notes!  TY! However I can't figure out how to adapt that (`.Where`) to cross through 2 files. As I understand it, `foreach` won't work because of lack of indexing.  At the risk of staring a new thread, I may rethink my subject question and explanation of my desired results for better clarity. (either edit this post or start [uhg]  anew [srry]).