# Modify xml file with C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML file content as below
and I need to modify line 4:

701.50,**24.0** to 701.50,**30.0**

How can I do this?

```
<CableLossConfig>
    <Std Val="CATM1">
        <Path Val="TX1">
            <Loss>701.50,24.0</Loss>
            <Loss>710.50,24.0</Loss>
            <Loss>713.50,24.0</Loss>
            <Loss>779.50,23.0</Loss>
            <Loss>782.00,23.0</Loss>
            <Loss>784.50,23.0</Loss>
            <Loss>826.50,30.0</Loss>
            <Loss>836.50,30.0</Loss>
            <Loss>846.50,30.0</Loss>
            <Loss>1712.50,37.0</Loss>
            <Loss>1732.50,37.0</Loss>
            <Loss>1752.50,37.0</Loss>
            <Loss>1852.50,37.0</Loss>
            <Loss>1880.00,37.0</Loss>
            <Loss>1907.50,37.0</Loss>
        </Path>
    </Std>
</CableLossConfig>
```

Comment: Can you Please Post the code you wrote to achieve this? Stackoverflow is site to get answers of the question your are facing error or stuck after you try your best.
kindly check other resources as well.

Comment: Do you want to change the First <Loss> value, or all the <Loss> with 701.50 value ?

Comment: Have a look at the XmlDocument class.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument?view=netframework-4.8    and   https://csharp.net-tutorials.com/xml/reading-xml-with-the-xmldocument-class/    should get you started

Comment: @Mark: I'd recommend using `XDocument` instead of `XmlDocument` - it's a much cleaner API in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            XElement tx1 = doc.Descendants("Path").Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("Val") == "TX1").FirstOrDefault();
            List<XElement> losses = tx1.Elements("Loss").ToList();
            XElement loss1 = losses[1];
            loss1.SetValue("701.50,30.0");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like a simple solution that does not require creating a C# model representing the structure of the xml file, I would suggest using the XDocument .net class (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument?view=netframework-4.8)

I found a quite nice example here on stackoverflow as well where a similar question was asked: [Edit specific Element in XDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18508765/edit-specific-element-in-xdocument)

I hope this helps!