# how to update an array inside xml in c#

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have a c# application where I have to save data inside an xml which works so far. But now I am trying to edit an Array inside a dataset so my xml looks like something like this at first:

```
   <ArrayOfAutokategorie xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Autokategorie id="13">
    <name>Test</name>
    <feeByDay>100</feeByDay>
    <feeByWeek>200</feeByWeek>
    HALOOOO
  </Autokategorie>
  <Autokategorie id="10">
    <name>1</name>
    <feeByDay>1</feeByDay>
    <feeByWeek>1</feeByWeek>
    
      HALOOOO
    
  </Autokategorie>
</ArrayOfAutokategorie>
```

And after my method something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <ArrayOfAutokategorie xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <Autokategorie id="1">
        <name>Hasan</name>
        <feeByDay>1235</feeByDay>
        <feeByWeek>1</feeByWeek>
        <car>
          value
          value
        </car>
      </Autokategorie>
    </ArrayOfAutokategorie>
```

This is the method I am trying to achieve this:

public void updateCategoryCar(string categoryName)
{

```
        serializerHelper sHelper = new serializerHelper();
        List<Autokategorie> carCategoryList = new List<Autokategorie>();
        string filepath = "category.xml";
        carCategoryList = sHelper.showData(typeof(List<Autokategorie>), "category.xml") as List<Autokategorie>;

        var xDoc = XDocument.Load(filepath);

        foreach (var category in carCategoryList)
        {
            if (category.name.Equals(categoryName))
            {
                                    
          
         xDoc.Descendants("car").FirstOrDefault().ReplaceWith(carSelector());

            }
        }
        xDoc.Save(filepath);



    }
```

My carRay is getting values from a method which works I debugged it, but still when I try to give the values inside carRay my category.car is still empty after the method, nothing changes from my xml.

the this is my filter method to add values to my array (rn just Haloo)

```
public string[] carSelector()
        {
            List<string> carElements = new List<string>();
            
            serializerHelper sHelper = new serializerHelper();
            List<Auto> carList = new List<Auto>();
            List<Autokategorie> carCategoryList = new List<Autokategorie>();
            List<string> categoryElements = new List<string>();

            string filePath = "car.xml";
            XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(filePath);

            carList = sHelper.showData(typeof(List<Auto>), filePath) as List<Auto>;
            carCategoryList = sHelper.showData(typeof(List<Autokategorie>), "category.xml") as List<Autokategorie>;

            foreach (var pair in carCategoryList.Zip(carList, (a, b) => new { A = a, B = b }))
            {
                if (pair.A.name.Equals(pair.B.categoryName))
                {
                }
            }
            carElements.Add("HALOOOO");

            car = carElements.ToArray();

            return car;

        }
```

Comment: You open the file do nothing with it and save. How to edit XDocument - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18508765/edit-specific-element-in-xdocument/18509281

Comment: Hi I just edited my code. But know the system tells me the Element returned null but car is inside category.xml it looks like this <car /> I tried to delete the empty space between car and / thought maybe because of that it could not be found but still getting the null error

Comment: Why not just create the array in c# in the first place?

Comment: For access car element need use `var car = doc.XPathSelectElement("ArrayOfAutokategorie/Autokategorie/car");`

Comment: You need decendants :  xDoc.Descendants("car").FirstOrDefault().ReplaceWith(carSelector());

Comment: @jdweng I added your code now it works. But when I save it I have two errors I do not seem to understand or find why happens. The first is the tags are deleted, this could be probably because of the replace with right? The other one is for example if I select id 13 the dataset with id 10 is edited and the other way around. I edted my answer. I added the method carSelector I suspect the error with saving without tags could be related to this.

Comment: Try : ReplaceWith(new XElement("car",carSelector()));

Comment: THanks it worked :) You guys really helped me out